# Como leer archivos en una red, desde un servidor con ubuntu?

Tags: python, odoo

```
def importar_archivos(self):
    import os


    dir2 = r'\\DESKTOP-3D6GNSP\Datos\Imp_exp_sugit\Importar'

    os.listdir(dir2)
    for filename in os.listdir(dir2):
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            print(os.path.join(dir2, filename))
            continue
        else:
            continue
```

Estoy trabajando con docker. Lo que intento es a través de un botón traer unos archivos que compartí a la red desde una pc cliente (con windows), y que el servidor, con ubuntu, me levante esos archivos y los lea.
La cuestion es que no me detecta la ruta, me dice que es inexistente.

Comment: Si entras en tu contenedor docker y haces un Ping al DESKTOP-3D6GNSP, te devuelve la IP correcta de ese equipo? Da la sensación de que no resuelve tu DNS interno

Comment: ping: unknown host DESKTOP-3D6GNSP
Me salta ese error

Comment: Si le tiro el Ping por ip me responde correctamente.